# OpenGL - How to scale an object from the centre? 

Tags: c, opengl, glut

My .c programme using glut creates an object and maps a texture onto that object. This object can then be manipulated by the user. When the object is scaled up then scaled down it moves outside of the window and out of view. How do i make sure the object stayes central when scaling or an alternative cant move outside of the window? I can include my code if needed.

Im thinking if I always scale from the centre of the object this would help but not sure how to do this as it seems to always scale from the corners which is causing it to move out the screen

Ok so the image seems to scale from the centre initially but when the image has been translated, any scaling after this causes it to move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as though the scaling operation is not scaling the object from the objects central position which will then cause the object to move away from its origin.

Make sure that you perform the scaling operation *before* any translation.

Comment: No it seems to be scaling from the corners. Is there an obvious reason for this?

Comment: it may simply be because the vertices glut generates are all positive. you could get around this my finding the width, height and depth of the object, translating by minus half these values using glTranslate then scale then translate again. a bit of a faf but should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need to create a collision detection algorithm between your object and the window edges.  If an edge or pixel of your object on the screen hits an edge of the window, it should not go any further.

There's plenty of material on the web regarding this, I'm sure you can find some examples.

Answer (score 0):

An object is a set of points. If all of their coordinates are, for example, positive, scaling it will appear to be done from a corner. To prevent this, you need to do some translating yourself.

```
glScaled(...);
glTranslated(/*-1 * center coordinates relative to the object*/);
//draw the object
```

Note that there is more than one way to center an object. The most simple one is to find the center of the bounding box.